# How can I avoid an underbake in a bundt pan?

Tags: cake

I've made a Cardamom Cream bundt cake twice now and both times it's dense and under baked after an hour baking time.  I'm thinking of whipping the egg whites to lighten the batter/cake than folding into the dry ingredients and cream.  Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your recipe and method.

Comment: Please be sure to include whether you have checked to be sure your oven is the proper temperature by using an oven thermometer, and describe the appearance and composition of your Bundt pan (light/dark metal, aluminum etc).

Comment: Recipe and method will help, but some early thoughts: are you sure your oven temperature is accurate? An oven thermometer can help to check. Are you sure your baking powder (if using) is fresh? After about 6 months it gets less effective and eventually it loses pretty much all its powers of leavening (by about a year old). Are you using the size of pan recommended by the recipe?

Comment: The recipe is here; https://www.nordicware.com/recipe/cardamom-cream-bundt-cake#.VhxysWuDXIU and I'm using nordicware Heritage bundt pan.  I hadn't thought about the baking powder being old. I'll get a fresh supply. I always think of the spices but not the components.  I do have an oven thermometer and adjusted the oven.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, a cake, unless it has a very sticky filling (fruit+sugar, chocolate...), can almost always be tested by pushing a toothpick/skewer right through the center (while in opened oven - oven gloves advised if inexperienced :), and checking whether the stick comes out clean - if not, give it extra baking time. If the exposed surface would brown too much by doing that, cover with aluminium foil.